# random position for the div in quizze game

Tags: angular

So I am creating quizze and I need the correct answer to be on random position every time I generate a new question. Right now it is always on the first div.
Any ideas on how can I randomize its possition?

```
<div class="row">
                <p (click)="selectedElement(3)" [ngClass]="{correct: nextBtnClickCounter == 1}" appSelectAnswer class="answer">
                    {{question.correct_answer}}
                </p>
                <p (click)='selectedElement(i)' appSelectAnswer class="answer" [ngClass]="{incorrect: nextBtnClickCounter == 1}" *ngFor='let item of question.incorrect_answers; let i = index'>
                    {{item}}
                </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to get the positioning randomized so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving logic of shuffling answers to Typescript.

```js
//component.ts
answers = [{"text": "A", "correct": true}, {"text": "B", "correct": false}]

getAnswers() {
    return this.answers.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
}

checkIfAnswerIsCorrect(answer) {
    return this.answers.find(a => a === answer).correct
}
```

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<p *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index" (click)="checkIfAnswerIsCorrect(answer)">{{answer.text}}</p>
```